# Solving differential algebraic equation with Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am looking to solve (in Python) a differential algebraic equation of the form `x'(t) = f(x(t),y(t))` subject to  `g(x)=0` for a function `g:R^n->R^m` defining the constraints on the state variable `x`. I think it should be possible to do that without needing to use `fsolve` and hence manually building up a numerical method.

For example, it seems reasonable this is possible using `sci.integrate.solve_ivp` or something similar. Can you suggest some specific effective option?

Comment: That situation is not possible. `x'=f(x)` is always a completely determined ODE. The semi-explicit DAE that you could use would have to look like `x'=f(x,y)`, `0=g(x,y)`. This is only index-1 if `g` can be solved for `y` following the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was not precise in the question. What I have is a DAE of index 2 of the form x'=f(x,y) with g(x)=0. Is there some solver for these kind of equations?

Comment: Not in scipy. You will need some other package that has DAE solvers. Some of the implicit solvers that accept singular "mass" matrices are correct for index 1 and 2.

Comment: Ok thank you, do you have some particular solver in mind? However this advice is more than enough, I will make some research.

Comment: @Dadeslam Would you mind giving an update? What did you finally choose?